# use php string to create a webpage

Tags: php

If I load the PHP variable $text with the following HTML code:

```
    $text = '' ;
    $text .= '<html lang="en">' ;
    $text .= '<head>' ;
    $text .= '   <meta charset="UTF-8">' ;
    $text .= '</head>' ;
    $text .= '<body>' ;
    $text .= '   hello <br>' ;
    $txt .= '</body>' ;
    $text .= '</html>' ;
```

What function do I use to have $text render as a new web-page?

Comment: This is pretty elementary: `echo`. If you're trying to learn PHP you'll need some kind of reference or guide. Consider [PHP the Right Way](http://phptherightway.com) as a starting point. If you're serious about making applications, consider a framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com) which has high-quality introduction material and a community that'll support you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty simple!
For generating a webpage by using PHP you have the following multiple options:
1. Using **echo** or its equal form, **print**
2. Add each one of your text input into the array and then use print in order to fetch the output by using its indices.
3. Constructing other data structure then retrieve their entries.
4. Other creative methods which could be defined by users.

*It has been recommended, do not use PHP as a Programming Language directly into an HTML webpage, it can be messed up so the best solution is using a **template engine** which PHP has the great source of them.*

***Twig*** and **Smarty** are the well-known template engines.

Also I will add a simple PHP template class which can render the page as you wish: [PHPsimpleTE](https://gist.github.com/daggerhart/730e8a9d79f37a461d985b158d0108ab)

Comment: Please don't answer low-quality questions, it will only consider further low-quality questions.

Comment: I will consider more.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

When you want to use PHP variables in HTML pages (or in your case; to create an HTML page) you can use `echo $text;`. However, this might not be your best option as you can use PHP *within* your HTML page:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php echo "hello"; ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

It seems to me you are quite new to programming and it might be a good idea to read some tutorials on how to use PHP and HTML together. You could start at the Mozilla Developer Network, which has a good guide on getting started:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web

If you want to create a new file using PHP, you can use `$file = fopen("newfile.php", "w")` and use `$text = "Your text here\n"; fwrite($file, $text);` to edit its contents. More about file creation can be found here:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Comment: Sorry for not adding more context to my question. I know I can use echo or print to use the HTML within the current page, but I want the code to be rendered within a new page. I have done this by saving the text in a file and using a URL request to see the results in a new page. However, I would prefer to have the text rendered immediately.

Comment: @monkey_boy You can just use `include()` to achieve this if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: include() will allow me to insert the code within an existing web page. i want the HTML code in $text to be used to generate a totally new and independent page. I am looking for a function that would trigger the creation of a new page only using the code in $text.

Comment: @monkey_boy You might want to look at `fopen()` and `fwrite()` in that case! Edited answer

Comment: Please don't answer low-quality questions, it will only consider further low-quality questions.

Comment: @GordonM I don't believe the question to be unsalvageable, with a couple edits the question will be improved and the asker will learn from that while still receiving an answer to their question. I even suggested an edit to the question to improve quality which is in the spirit of the 'be nice' rules: "Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions. Don't expect new users to know all the rules — they don't. And be patient while they learn."